# How to change the titlebar's font size and height in Gnome Shell windows

Tags: fonts, gnome, styles, gnome-shell

Is it possible to customize the font size and other properties of the window titlebars in gnome-shell?

Answer (score 2):

You can trim the title bar aspect with

- Open Terminal
- Create file "gtk.css", on /home/(userdirectory)/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

  $ cd /home/(userdirectory) //change with your username directory
  $ gedit .config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
- insert code below

  .header-bar.default-decoration { padding-top : 4px; padding-bottom : 4px; }
  .header-bar.default-decoration .button.titlebutton { padding-top : 2.5px; padding-bottom : 2.5px; }
- Quit and Save Gedit
- Restart Gnome Shell (Alt+F2, r)

Answer (score -1):

Install gnome-tweak-tool and under "Fonts" there is "window title font"

[image]

Comment: Thanks that works for font type and size, but I also want to change the titlebars height, color and maybe icons.

Comment: @nilfric For that you have to use themes. Google themes or how to create your own theme

Comment: Hmm, I hoped there would be a way to change this in gnome-session.css, but I can't find any class that references the titlebar.